# How can I use IMPORTXML to get text from a unordered list?

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I have a number of URLs that contain lists of information I would like to bring into a google spreadsheet. An an example of the code from one of the URLs is as follows:

```
<div class="mb-2 card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <ul>
            <li class="pb-1">
                <b class="pr-2">Line 1:</b>
                 " SOME TEXT I WANT "
            </li>
            <li class="pb-1">
                <b class="pr-2">Line 2:</b>
                " MORE TEXT I WANT "
            </li>       
            <li class="pb-1">
                <b class="pr-2">Line 3:</b>
                " MORE TEXT I WANT "
            </li>                                                                                                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is is the formula I have been using:

`=IMPORTXML(C2,"//li[@class='pb-1']/text()")`

Where C2 contains the URL.

I would expect this to return:

**Line 1:** SOME TEXT I WANT
**Line 2:** MORE TEXT I WANT
**Line 3:** MORE TEXT I WANT

Instead, it only manages to get the text in the  tag and not the next I want. So the result is:

**Line 1:

Line 2:

Line 3:**

I have also tried getting every line item regardless of class using this:

`=IMPORTXML(C2,"//li")`

But I have the same problem.

I've seen a lot of advice about IMPORTXML not working when a website uses scripts, but I don't believe this is the issue as I've loaded the website with scripts disabled and the desired text still displays.

Any idea how I can get the text I want? I am also open to using any other methods you know of outside of the IMPORTXML function.

Comment: Hi. Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Would you also provide an example of the data that you want to return based on your url.

Comment: I would expect `//li[@class='pb-1']/text()` not to return the contents of the `b` elements. The XPath expression identifies _only_ the text nodes which are direct children of the `li` elements, which would be blank lines alternating with `" SOME TEXT I WANT "`, `" MORE TEXT I WANT "`, etc. Are you sure your example XML correctly reflects the data?

Comment: In your question, can you provide a sample URL for testing your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Going strictly by your sample xml,

```
//ul[li[@class='pb-1']]/*/normalize-space(.)
```

should output

```
Line 1: " SOME TEXT I WANT "
Line 2: " MORE TEXT I WANT "
Line 3: " MORE TEXT I WANT "
```